# How to load Java API (.jar files) dynamically in C#?

Tags: java, .net, jar

I have an ASP.NET web application written in C#. I can load .NET APIs in the form of dlls dynamically and call methods in them from my application. I want to know if I can do the same with Java APIs (Jar files). Can I load Jar files dynamically at runtime and call functions within them?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512124/use-a-jar-java-library-api-in-c

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617499/executing-jar-file-within-a-c-sharp-dot-net-application